# matlab2tikz : Wrong fonts in Axis/Tick labels and Legend in tikz figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, matlab2tikz

I am using Matlab 2016b on a Linux 64 bit machine.

I have the following figure in Matlab:

[image: matlab figure]

Using a script, I make some changes to the figure text and then call `matlab2tikz` function. This script is given below.

```
%% Script to modify text properties and call matlab2tikz
openfig('example.fig')
hfig = gcf;
haxis = gca;

haxis.XLabel.String = 'XLABEL (x 1000)'; 
haxis.XLabel.FontName = 'Lucida Sans Typewriter';
haxis.YLabel.String = 'YLABEL (30 runs)'; 
haxis.YLabel.FontName = 'Lucida Sans Typewriter';

% change tick label fonts
haxis.FontName = 'Lucida Sans Typewriter';
haxis.Legend.FontName = 'Lucida Sans Typewriter';
haxis.XTickLabel = {'2','4','6','8'};
matlab2tikz('example.tex','width','\figurewidth');
close all
```

When I include the `ex.tex` in the Latex file, the pgfplot produced has

1. wrong fonts
2. wrong x-tick labels,

as shown in the screenshot:

[image: pgflot figure]

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Please, give us a full description **here**.  Have a complete and working MWE, that resembles your problem. (That is from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.)  Instead of linking to external site, please include the images into your question directly.  That would help us, to help you.

Comment: The font problem is probably due to "Lucida Sans Typewriter" not being a valid latex font. Do you compile with xelatex or lualatex? Those can access to OS fonts, but standard pdflatex cannot. Inspect the `log` file produced by latex looking for "missing font" warnings.

Comment: That ticklabels are wrong might be due to a "translation" error by `matlab2tikz`, but without seeing the actual text file, I cannot say for sure.